# XOR in a formula field using IF

Tags: formula, formula-field

`XOR` operator is not available in the Salesforce formula editor

I am looking to implement `XOR` using the `IF` operator, instead of doing this :

`( A && !B ) || ( !A && B )`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A XOR B` is equivalent to `IF(A,!B,B)`

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ A     ║ B     ║ A XOR B                 ║ IF(A,!B,B)                     ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ true  ║ true  ║ true XOR true = false   ║ IF(true,!true,true) = false    ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ true  ║ false ║ true XOR false = true   ║ IF(true,!false,false) = true   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ false ║ true  ║ false XOR true = true   ║ IF(false,!true,true) = true    ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ false ║ false ║ false XOR false = false ║ IF(false,!false,false) = false ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: This answer could use some additional detail. You've asserted that `IF(A,!B,B)` is equivalent (and it truly is, given that `A` and `B` are either boolean variables, or expressions that result in booleans), but where is your proof? Including a truth table that breaks down the evaluation of your `IF()` would be helpful.

Comment: Also, is this truly any better than the more traditional approach? Sure, it's a few characters shorter, but what effects does this have on the compiled size of the formula? [What are the compiled costs of each Formula function](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148493/what-are-the-compiled-costs-of-each-formula-function) would help in answering this.

Comment: @DerekF added the table, the compile size is about the same : 30 vs 32 (IF)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the shortest way to write an XOR in a formula field, you could use this:

```
A!=B
```