# Compiled formula is too big to execute (5,016 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to merge some field values using formula field but its hitting the limit.

> Compiled formula is too big to execute (5,016 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters

each fields are formula field in itself, which again references some other fields

- I understand that's the reason, but is there a way to shorten below code? I am not sure if CASE would help here.

```
IF(ISBLANK(Classification_ANF_formula_GILD_E__c),'',
Classification_ANF_formula_GILD_E__c & ' ; ' )
&
IF(ISBLANK(Classification_CF_formula_GILD_E__c),'',
Classification_CF_formula_GILD_E__c & ' ; ' )
&
IF(ISBLANK(Classification_HBV_formula_GILD_E__c),'',
Classification_HBV_formula_GILD_E__c & ' ; ' )
&
IF(ISBLANK(Classification_HCV_formula_GILD_E__c),'',
Classification_HCV_formula_GILD_E__c & ' ; ' )
&
IF(ISBLANK(Classification_ONC_formula_GILD_E__c),'',
Classification_ONC_formula_GILD_E__c & ' ; ' )
&
IF(ISBLANK(Classification_HIV_formula_GILD_E__c),'',
Classification_HIV_formula_GILD_E__c & ' ; ' )
& 
IF(ISBLANK(Classification_CT_formula_GILD__c),'', 
Classification_CT_formula_GILD__c )
&
IF(ISBLANK(Classification_INF_formula_GILD_E__c),'',
Classification_INF_formula_GILD_E__c & ' ; ' )
```

Comment: [What are the compiled cost of each formula function](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148493/what-are-the-compiled-costs-of-each-formula-function/) would be a good reference for you.

Comment: This looks too small to hit 5k. Are each of these fields a formula in itself?

Comment: Or may be at least one field is a Long Textarea field?

Comment: Manjith - each fields mentioned here are formula fields itself, which again reference another text field.. I cant go with workflow update option either.

Comment: well, you can get rid of at least one if...  i think you may have mixed the order of Classification_CT_formula_GILD__c and Classification_INF_formula_GILD_E__c, but the one that doesn't have to have the ' ; ' concatenated does not need the surrounding if statement.

Comment: Try BLANKVALUE function in lieu of IF