# Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute

Tags: formula, formula-field

Currently I have a formula consisting of various fields where each of the field itself is a formula. This results in a formula is too big to compile error. I am wondering if there are any ways optimize the formula to avoid such error.

The current formula takes the score of all my various components and divides it by the count of the number of components used if they are not blank.

This is my overall score formula:
[image]

This is my communication score formula:

[image]

Comment: You can try switching CASE with IF

Comment: Or if the fields are picklist, the value of the option could be 1 or 0, and then you could try to add them, but not sure if won't just get `'100010'`.

Comment: [What are the compiled costs of each formula function?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148493/what-are-the-compiled-costs-of-each-formula-function) is a good reference.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/384455/how-do-i-derive-percentage-value-score-from-my-other-scored-components.  You might be able to use "1" and "0" for your picklist API values and thus use  VALUE function instead of IFs.  But given the complexity of your calculations, you may have to replace some of your formula fields with number fields calculated by Flow or Apex.